# Is there a way to type coloured words on a sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a house, and I want to put signs around of what is this particular section. However, I want to colour the words on each sign for different sections in the house, since the house is very big ( a bunker, actually). Is there a way for me to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can colour minecraft signs with various colours as shown:

1. Dark Red    §4
2. Red         §c
3. Gold        §6
4. Yellow      §e
5. Dark Green  §2
6. Green       §a
7. Aqua        §b
8. Dark Aqua   §3
9. Dark Blue   §1
10. Blue       §9
11. Light Purple§d
12. Dark Purple§5
13. White      §f
14. Gray       §7
15. Dark Gray  §8
16. Black      §0

You can also change the font by:

->Bold  §l

->Strikethrough §m

->Underline §n

->Italic    §o

->Obfuscated (The text looks like this: qoiejfa... flashing randomness) §k

note: You will have to enter this at the start of each line on the sign. If the text overflows to a second line and this code isn’t present at the start, the text color of the second line will be the default black.

Hope this will help!

taken from:[https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-text-color-for-signs-in-minecraft/#:~:text=Using%20color%20codes&text=In%20Minecraft%2C%20place%20a%20sign,code%20before%20the%20second%20line](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-text-color-for-signs-in-minecraft/#:%7E:text=Using%20color%20codes&text=In%20Minecraft%2C%20place%20a%20sign,code%20before%20the%20second%20line).